# javascript what's the different between this two pieces of code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to javascript and node. 
1st:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  articleProvider.findAll(function(error, docs){
      res.render('index.jade', { locals: {
        title: 'Blog',
        articles:docs
        }
      });
  });
});
```

2nd

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  articleProvider.findAll(function(error, docs){
      res.render('index.jade', {
        title: 'Blog',
        articles:docs
        }
      );
  });
});
```

1st code is from this tutorial http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb, but doesn't work.
2nd code did work, and i just don't know why? Other parts are exactly same.

Comment: So you're basically asking what `locals` is for?

Comment: Wow... You're right. Nice work making that really hard to see.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What errors do you get?

Comment: yes, I caught that about 9/10ths of a second after I posted it. And noted the plus one before I deleted it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In earlier versions of Express you needed to put the vars you wanted to make available to your Jade template in the `locals` field of that parameter to `res.render`.

That changed in 3.x so that all the fields of that parameter are available to the rendered template as locals.